# What happens to the human body when hit by a magic lightning and a frozen arrow at the same time?

Tags: internal-consistency, magic, anatomy, electricity, cryogenics

What happens to the human body when hit by a magic lightning and a frozen arrow at the same time? The lightning power is strong enough to shock but not to kill.

The point where the ''combined spell'' hits is the right shoulder. The projectile is an arrow made of ice infused with electric magic launched by a cryomancer. The arrow travels at the same speed as a thrown javelin.

Yes the arrow has weight.

Can the shock cauterize the wound, or will it cause a ''painless'' death since the mix of both cold and shock?

Comment: Does the magic arrow have any mass at all? You should consider that an arrow is still a weapon designed to kill. i admit javelin speeds are slower than regular arrow speeds, but even at those speeds it is still capable of severe damage, so its not just electric shock and cold damage to consider

Comment: Is the target wearing armor, and if so, what kind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It was a bad idea.**

The cryomancer is used to cold stuff, but electricity is new to her.  The extreme coldness and consequent superconductivity increases the charge on the arrow.  As the arrow approaches its target, the charge causes it to be repelled so that it slows (crackling, with corona discharges) in the air.  It comes to a stop about a foot from the target and then gently drifts down.

The target reaches out in curiosity and grabs at the arrow but it moves away, still repelled.

The cryomancer snorts in disgust.  Her archer friend rolls his eyes.

Comment: damn your answers are always so fun, but is it legit? would the arrow actually be repelled?

Comment: Probably best not to think too much about it, because how much cold power or electrical charge can a real arrow carry?

Comment: That is a lame comment by me; sorry.  The idea behind this is that the arrow and target have like charges, and so the arrow is repelled.  Check out http://holbert.faculty.asu.edu/wise/balloons.htm

Answer (score 6):

**Electrical Discharge Damage**

How much of a discharge will it take to kill a person? Well after a quick google search the minimum fatal amp value seems to be around 20-70 milliamps of current across the heart. so so long as the discharge is lower than that then they should survive,

You've said the power is not strong enough to kill, so one would assume that that would mean no matter where the arrow hits it is designed not to kill so would need to be lower than the upper estimate of 70 milliamps. however you have designed a magic that won't kill and then added it to a weapon that IS designed to kill... an arrow...

**Freezing Damage**

Would the freezing arrow make it much worse? no actually. Ice is actually a fairly poor conductor, and it is actually the ions trapped within the ice that allows for the electricity to be conducted. so if the magic imparted the cold damage before the electric damage, then actually your making the electric damage less powerful.

If it was just Flash freezing the surface of the body, then it'll be painful but no long lasting effects. however if the freezing had depth and enough strength then it'll cause frostbite (at the lowest level) which can easily be fatal especially if its deep into the shoulder, and if not fatal then it will probably render the arm and should next to useless for the rest of the victims life.

**Kinetic Damage**

If your arrow has mass roughly similar to a regular arrow then being launched at "javelin" speeds could still easily kill a person. if it hits the shoulder then it could still break ribs, the shoulder blade, to severe damage to muscles. if it is an entirely magic arrow and has no mass, then all of the above doesn't really matter. Its magic, the spell that causes it is designed to either kill or not kill, and its up to you as the writer what effects it causes

**Non Fatal Magic**

If you want to incapacitate a person with magic without causing last damage, then get rid of the freezing aspect (Personal Opinion) stick to emulating what happens in real life.  Tazers use non fatal amounts of power but over a continual discharged it incapacitates the body, (and apparently is extremely painful) but unless a very rare set of circumstances come together it is non lethal.

Answer (score 2):

Arrows much like bullets aren’t physical avatars of death itself. Being hit by one or the other won’t instantly kill a person unless it hits one of a few very specific spots. Instead, these things will often leave a person wounded, scared, or annoyed depending both on the person in question and where they were hit.

Electricity has the capacity to burn flesh, but it also forces the muscles to contract and therefore causes a person to be temporarily paralyzed. Ice likewise has the same potential. If these two effects were magically combined, you might expect the resulting effect to leave a person stunned and in pain.